# How jump to the ADDRESS in Keil on lpc4078?

Tags: arm, keil, lpc

I have bootloader, when good jobed in lpc2xxx. But, when I copy this to lpc4078, bootloader not jump to main programm.

I tried:
1) Use `#define USER_FLASH_START 0x8000`

```
__asm void boot_jump(uint32_t address)
{
    LDR SP, [R0]
    LDR PC, [R0, #4]
}

main()
{

  bool t = true;
  while(t)
  {
    ...WORKING CODE...
    uart << "Hello, World!!!";
  }

  uart << "END";
  __disable_irq();
  __set_CONTROL(0);
  __set_MSP(stack_adr);

  SCB->VTOR = (USER_FLASH_START & 0x1FFFFF80);
  boot_jump(USER_FLASH_START);
}
```

2)  Use `#define USER_FLASH_START 0x8000`

```
void JumpToAppAt(unsigned int * vtbp)
{
  __disable_irq();
  __set_MSP(vtbp[0]); // load SP
  ((void (*)(void)) vtbp[1])(); // go...
}

main()
{

    bool t = true;
  while(t)
  {
    ...WORKING CODE...
    uart << "Hello, World!!!";
  }

  uart << "END";
     __disable_irq();
     __set_CONTROL(0);
     __set_MSP(stack_adr);

     SCB->VTOR = (USER_FLASH_START & 0x1FFFFF80);
     JumpToAppAt((unsigned int *) USER_FLASH_START);
}
```

Main programm not start(.

I thought what not work MAIN_PROGRAMM and tried:

3) Use `#define USER_FLASH_START 0x0`, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

LPC2xxx are based on ARM7 while LPC4078 is based on Cortex-M4. Regarding the reset vector, I see that you have adjusted to using the 2nd entry of the vector table. Please make sure that the addresses stored in the vector table have their LSB set to 1, i.e. **bit[0] = 1**, because this bit indicates Thumb instructions, and the Cortex-M4 processor only supports Thumb instructions. ([reference](https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0553/latest/the-cortex-m4-instruction-set/about-the-instruction-descriptions/restrictions-when-using-pc-or-sp))